# Dungeon Defenders web discconect?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I've been finding that I'm get dropped out of a startling number of games for connectivity reasons. I even got dropped out of *my own private game* right before the end of the boss fight in The Summit.

I have a healthy internet connection, and I was running off of ethernet at the time of that particular lag out.

I haven't noticed an effect like this in any other game.

Thoughts?

Comment: Try turning down your graphical settings?

Comment: I misspoke. It's not that my computer is seizing up, it's that I'm getting dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trendynet is a fickle beast; [you're certainly not the only one.](https://www.google.com/search?q=dungeon%20defenders%20dropped%20connection) If your game loses connection with their servers (or the Steam servers) for more than a second or so. The game is dropped immediately.

At this point, there's not much that can be done about it until Trendy fixes the issue on their end.